# How do I make Spring call a validator on a REST service?

Tags: java, spring, rest, hibernate-validator

I have studied many, many answers and I still can't see what I'm doing wrong.

I have a REST service controller which takes a bean as a parameter and I would like to validate that the fields on the bean are properly set.

The following is (a portion of) my configuration object.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({...})
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public Validator validator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean validatorBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        return validatorBean;
    }

    @Override
    public Validator getValidator() {
        return validator();
    }
}
```

I can't tell if those are necessary, but I can tell they're never called, so maybe they're in the wrong place?

The following is (a portion of) my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I don't think el is necessary for what I'm doing, but I included it in case it made a difference.

Here is (a portion of) my bean class that needs to be validated:

```
public class ContactInfo {
    @NotNull
    @Size(min=1, max=50)
    private String phone;
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}
```

And finally, this is (a portion of) the Rest Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/contact")
public class ContactController {
    private static final String USER_ID_ATTRIBUTE = "userId";

    @Autowired
    private Validator validator;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("contactService")
    private ContactService service;

    @RequestMapping("/submit")
    public void submitContact(
        @Valid @RequestBody ContactInfo formData, BindingResult result) throws Exception {
        assert(validator != null);
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            throw new Exception("I don't like it one bit.");
        }
        service.submitContact(formData);
    }
}
```

In the debugger, I can see that the validator passed in is an OptionalValidatorFactoryBean, and result.hasErrors() is always false.

The JSON passed in to the controller includes this:

```
{ "phone":"" }
```

I think that should trigger a validation error because it doesn't meet the minimum size.

Comment: Remove the contents of you AppConfig class -- you don't need to do anything other than include the dependency in order to have jsr303 validation working (and that's all you need at the moment).

Comment: Just tried that.  No luck.  Still no validation happening.  I figure it's something simple, but it looks like it's not noticing the dependency.

Comment: I found some advice in another thread that said JSR 303 doesn't work in Hibernate Validator 5.x.  I downgraded to 4.3.1.Final, and then javax.validation 1.0.0.GA.  That seems to cause some validation to happen.

Comment: You don't need to hack the validation results yourself you know. Spring will return an appropriate message to the caller should validation fail.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by hacking the results.  This is similar to a form submission, but done as a RESTful service with a JSON payload.  I am aware that Spring can handle form submissions nicely, but this is not actually a form submission.  I actually need to return information to the user about what the service was able to do, including the validation messages, but not just those.  (And it seems to be working now.)